# serial upvoting reversal reputation cap

Tags: discussion

I was just the "victim" of a large number of upvotes - which I suspect the script will catch:

[image]

I can't imaging how you can upvote that quickly - 9 votes in 23 seconds is spectacular.

Question I have: if one ends up running into the rep cap for the day, and subsequent upvotes get no rep, then do these "uncounted" votes become counted votes after a serial voting reversal?

I was curious how the system works - I might not hit the cap today, otherwise I could just do the wait-and-see experiment.

Comment: I have no idea how the system works, but how do you know that it was just not many people upvoting you in that timeframe? (I seem to recall a mother meta post that whenever users think they have been serially up-/downvoted, most often they have not, and it was accident)

Comment: @ACuriousMind It's true - I don't _know_ that. But really - unless the rep system was backlogged and just caught up, I can't see how else you could get single upvotes on that many different questions in such a short interval. 9 votes. 23 seconds. Occam's razor.

Comment: You may have a misguided fan. 9 upvotes in 23 seconds wouldn't be hard if he opened your recent activity from your profile in multiple pages and upvoted them in succession without reading them.

Comment: @alemi - "if _he_ opened"? Or she... my daughter is a physicist too, and she is very sensitive about gender stereotypes in physics. So I'm trying to be in her corner on this one.

Comment: Sorry, old habit formed in me by a historically gender biased society. I will try to be better.

Comment: (That's why I advocate "they" to refer to unknown single persons) OT: You can always force a recalc of your reputation, that would get rid of any oddities that the possible reversal of votes might cause.

Comment: @Floris I really do feel bad. I usually try to be conscience of that, but evidently not enough.  You have left me a better person, thank you.

Comment: Did it get reversed now?

Comment: @kylekanos - no, not yet. Time to flag for mods, or do I wait?

Comment: @Floris: I don't think mods can do anything about that (I could be wrong though). If it hasn't taken them off by now, I can't imagine it coming off at all. It's usually at midnight utc that the script is run, so it should have caught it by now.

Comment: We can't do anything directly but we can contact the SE team and ask them to look into it. I'll do that now. (Although you could also do the same.) BTW the way to get attention is to flag one of the posts that was voted on, not to flag _this_ post.

Comment: @davidz thanks for teaching me that - I will know for next time.

Comment: The voting has finally been reversed - apparently it needed manual intervention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer can be found here: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Also relevant: [How to act when you're being serial upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124842/how-to-act-when-youre-being-serial-upvoted)

In particular:

> ## What else should I know about this subject?
>
> ### Reversals trigger a reputation recalculation.
>
> Whenever serial voting gets reversed, all days involved in the serial voting will be recalculated as if the serial votes had never happened, and any reputation you might have lost due to those serial votes hitting the reputation cap will be given to you at that time. **Serial voters will not prevent you from gaining reputation that you deserve**.

Comment: As usual, a carefully sourced answer. Thank you.